# Creating an MongoDB domain model that can be used in both ASP.NET and Win RT apps?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am attempting to create a simple domain model designed to be used in an ASP.NET Web API project with MongoDB and the C# driver as found in the example located [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/#bsondocument-object-model-vs-your-own-domain-classes). The example shows the following entity:

```
public class Entity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My issue is that this class contains an Id property of type ObjectId belonging to the MongoDB.Bson namespace which needs to be referenced within the Visual Studio project. Now this is all well and good except when I want to use this entity in my Win RT (Windows Store App) project in which case I cannot reference MongoDB as no appropriate bindings exist.

In my C# Win RT project I want consume from my REST API which will return JSON containing properties of this entity and hence I would like to reuse the Entity class in the deserialization with JSON.NET.

What is the best way to remove the MongoDB dependency from my entity class? Would it be best to make my Id property as type string instead? If so are there implications that I should be aware of with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'd just make it a `string`. Ideally though, you might consider that the model you use in your WinRt application is a view model and doesn't use the native BSON data types.

When I've done something like this though, I've normally exposed a view model and have not shared the internal database representation of an object with clients. It's often necessary as the UI needs more sophisticated and resolved values (things like the `ObjectId` aren't as useful as having the data the id might point to).

By making it a `string`, you won't loose much in C#, as the conversion is super simple and fast anyway.

Alternatively, you should consider using the `BsonClassMap` as documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/). You could split type decoration from the types and make any modifications you want only on the server.